# Telegram unity app opens in browser

Tags: webapps

When I open the Telegram unity webapp on Ubuntu 14.04 it opens the app with a blank screen and then opens my web browser with the Telegram web app as shown in the screen grab:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: I got the same error and reported it to the Telegram developer but they just said no there is no problem and removed my bug report.
This is the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/libunity-webapps/+bug/1407275
Go there and tell them that you have the same problem and link to your screen shot and we might get it fixed.

Comment: @laserpirate So I contacted a moderator and had your *deleted answer* undeleted *as a comment* and you should be able to continue editing it. For the future: don't scream at moderators or reviewers as not everyone is as lenient as me.

Comment: I have reported that I have the same bug and included the screen grab

Comment: It was a bug and fixed

Answer (score 0):

There was a small update through the PPA for Telegram today and it resolved the bug on my system. Thank you everybody